# How to build foundation from scss

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Is it possible to build foundation from the .scss files simply using scss?

If I run:
scss compile --watch foundation.scss

I get an error:
error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - compile

How to build the whole suite just using scss?

Comment: Please provide some more details and code. A search for the `rb_sysopen` error might give some hints.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372542/sass-can-be-converted-to-css-but-not-working-with-watch-command

Comment: Thanks. Using the example given in the thread you have posted, I was able to get past the error.


scss --watch foundation.scss:foundation.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      write foundation.css
      write foundation.css.map

However, the found.css file contains only Heading comments.. no CSS.

Comment: You have to provide more information. We do not know the structure and setup of your project.

Answer (score 0):

We use gulp for the most setups.

See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/package.json#L7

Comment: Yes, this is documented to some degree on the Zurb site, however, the goal of this, is to build with the scss alone, and without dependencies on 3rd party applications.